# How to read output of running project from Visual Studio Extension window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I want to create a Visual Studio extension that read the output of the currently running project and show it in structured way (the format is known and should be same for all the users of this extension) (current format is not really readable as is)

How can I get the output of the running project into my window? (something like the default output window of VS)

another alternative is to write to some stream that will push the output to my window. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Take a look of this: [VSConstants.GUID_OutWindowGeneralPane Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb131536(v=vs.120)). Is this what you want?